# Cx of circle is not updated after drag event?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, coordinates, drag

I am writing a graph with d3's draggable svg's circles. So far I have something like this:

```
var drag1 = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function() { 
        var t = d3.select(this);
        return {x: t.attr("x") + d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[0],
                y: t.attr("y") + d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[1]};
    })
    .on("drag", function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i){
            return "translate(" + [ 0,d3.event.y ] + ")"
        })
    });
d3.selectAll("circle").call(drag1);
```

I would like to store `oldY` on `mousedown` and assign `newY` on `mouseup`.

```
    .on("mousedown", function(d){
        var th = d3.select(this);

        d.oldY = +th.attr("cy");
    })
    .on("mouseup", function(d){
        var th = d3.select( this );

        var coordinates = [0, 0];
        coordinates = d3.mouse( this.parentNode );
        console.log( "d3.mouse( this.parentNode )[1]  " + d3.mouse( this.parentNode )[1] );
        console.log("d3.event.pageY  "  + d3.event.pageY);
        console.log("th.attr('cy')  " + th.attr("cy"));

        //?? 
        th.attr("cy",d3.event.pageY  );

        d.newY = ?? what ??
        console.log(d);
    });
```

I need `oldY` and `newY` for another function's purposes how can I do this to get circle's coordinates after drag or update cx and cy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're implementing dragging by setting a transform on the object, that is independent of cx, cy so they never change.

If you want the transformed co-ordinates you can call [getBBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) to get the bounding box and since you're dragging a circle circle's centre will be the centre of the bounding box. getBBox will include both the transform and cx, cy values.